# How to randomly sample a fraction of the rows in a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, collect

I am trying to get the data frame as a list of records using collect function and it is very slow for a data frame with 4000+ columns. Are there any faster alternatives? I even tried doing df.persist() before calling .collect() but even that didn't help.

```
val data = df
  .collect()
  .map(
    x ⇒
      x.toSeq.toList.map(_ match {
        case null  ⇒ ""
        case other ⇒ other.toString
      })
  )
  .toList
```

EDIT (from comments):

So the use case is to get the records from the dataframe and show them as sample data.

Comment: Why are you calling `collect()`?

Comment: so it will give me array[Row] and then I can iterate on that Row to get the row data. So the use case it to get the records from the data frame and show them as sample data.

Comment: @Ashwin You should never call `collect()`, except for debugging / development. Or if you are really sure you are collecting a final result which is small. For sample data, there a few methods on the [**Dataset API**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) which may be useful for that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes I agree I realized that after running it. Even the docstring for collect method mentions that    "Running collect requires moving all the data into the application's driver process, and doing so on a very large dataset can crash the driver process with OutOfMemoryError." Looking at the other alternatives I can only see head(n) so I can get n sample records, but I am thinking it will do the same as collect, do you have any recommendation?

Comment: @Ashwin `head` will only move the first element, so no that heavy. Also, there `take(n)` to take the first n element to the driver, you can control how many elements aren't too many. But, even better, there are sampling methods, which you can call first to get a random sampling over the data, and then call collect or take over the result.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez oops my bad, I meant take(n). But let me check the sampling methods, I see a bunch of them. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and comments, it sounds like you're looking for a way to sample columns and rows.  Here's a simple way to take N random columns and randomly [`sample`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@sample(fraction:Double):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) a fraction of the rows in a DataFrame:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "a", 10.0, 100L),
  (2, "b", 20.0, 200L),
  (3, "c", 30.0, 300L)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

import scala.util.Random

// e.g. Take 3 random columns and randomly pick ~70% of rows
df.
  select(Random.shuffle(df.columns.toSeq).take(3).map(col): _*).
  sample(70.0/100).
  show
// +---+---+---+
// | c1| c2| c4|
// +---+---+---+
// |  1|  a|100|
// |  3|  c|300|
// +---+---+---+
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do but instead of randomly picking columns, I need to get all the columns but only a few rows probably like 20.

Comment: @Ashwin, then all you need would be something like `df.sample(20.0/df.count)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should limit the number of rows you fetch to the driver, `collect` will get everything.

Either use

```
df.limit(20).collect
```

or

```
df.take(20)
```

Also, I should be faster if you first map your `Row` to a `List[String]` and then collect. Like this, this operation runs on the executors:

```
val data = df
  .map(
    x ⇒
      x.toSeq.toList.map(_ match {
        case null  ⇒ ""
        case other ⇒ other.toString
      })
  )
  .take(20)
  .toList
```